# Parameterized Modules (SystemVerilog)

Tags: boolean, embedded, logic, verilog, system-verilog

I have read the book *["Digital Design and Computers Architecture"](https://www.elsevier.com/books/digital-design-and-computer-architecture/harris/978-0-12-394424-5)* by David Harris and I have a question about SystemVerilog examples in this book. After the introduction in the "parameterized construction", which is `# (parameter ...)`, this operator is used almost in every example.

For example, the "subtractor" module from this book:

```
module subtractor #(parameter N = 8)
(input logic [N - 1:0] a,b,
output logic [N - 1:0] y);
assign y = a - b;
endmodule
```

What's the reason of using `N` in this code?
Can't we just write the following?:

```
input logic [7:0] a,b,
output logic [7:0] y);
```

Moreover, such parameters are used in almost every example further in the book but, as for me, there is no reason for using it. *We can set the number of bits directly in square brackets without using additional "parameters".*

So, what is the reason of such form of coding above?

Comment: In a nutshell, parameters are for generalization of modules.

Comment: reusability is the main purpose of parameterized modules.

Comment: @sharvil111 thank you for your reply

Comment: @KaranShah thank you too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of parameters serves a number of purposes.

1. It is always a better programming practice to use a symbolic name associated with a value than using a literal value directly. `DATA_WIDTH` instead of `N` would have been a more appropriate example. This documents the meaning of the value.
2. When a change to that value is needed, you have a single place to make that change, and less chance that you'll miss a change, or change an unintended value.
3. The use of parameters allows you to re-use the same code in many different places by creating a template and then overriding the parameter values as needed.